# Using numerical value of Solve

Tags: equation-solving

Suppose I solve an equation
*y=Solve[x+3==8,x]*

and I want to get the numerical value of y, how do I do that? I mean, if I want to work with my result and evaluate, for example
*y-2*
it will not work, because y is not in the form of a number, but rather *{{y->3}}*. How can I convert it into a number?

Thanks

Comment: `y = x /. Solve[x + 3 == 8, x][[1]]`

Comment: [common pitfalls / Using the result of functions that return replacement rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/5478)

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
(* #1 *)
Solve[x + 3 == 8, x] // Part[#, 1, 1, 2] &
(* #2 *)
Last @@ Last @@ Solve[x + 3 == 8, x] 
(* #3 *)
x /. # & @@ Solve[x + 3 == 8, x]
```

Out:

```
5
5
5
```

Comment: Or `y = Solve[x + 3 == 8, x][[1, 1, 2]]` less typing :)

Comment: Last @ Reduce[x + 3 == 8]

Comment: No competition Uncharted, just pointing out that your first example can be shortened :)

Comment: :) I know. It's just for fun.

Comment: Okay then!  Good to see someone with a passion for anonymous functions and the apply function, continue sir :)

Comment: Solve[x + 3 == 8, x] /. {{_ -> n_}} -> n